# Reading Wi-Fi Tags using Android Device

Tags: java, android

If aeroscout Wi-Fi tag is configured in beaconing mode, it will sends beacons.
     I need to know whether we can get RSSI value from these beacons by using Wi-Fi API on android phone same as RSSI value of Wi-Fi access points.
     I have  Samsung SII mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code

```
 WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (mWifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
     mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi()
     mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSsid()
    }
```

Comment: It means Scanning for wifi-tags is same as scanning for wifi-access points, no difference is both cases.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation, a ScanResult (triggered by WifiManager) contains "The detected signal level in dBm". See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html